# How to check for a badge number on app launch on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I check if my app has a badge number.  When I send a push notification the users, it add a "1" as the badge number to the icon. I would like to check if there is a badge number when the user launches the app and direct them a view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd propably make use of the property `applicationIconBadgeNumber` of the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`'s application.

So, to be clear:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     application.applicationIconBadgeNumber =  1; /*some number...*/

     //or to read the number

     int appIconBadge = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber;

}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to keep track of it yourself in the app.  Your delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: will be called upon the notification and the user presses the action button and it receives the notification payload.

If you app is running in the foreground, the delegates application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: will be called.  In this case you could have an integer value and increment it to keep track of the number of notifications you have.  It also receives the notification payload.

Alternately, without knowing anything about your design, you could have a web service that the app could query to determine whatever number of items you are looking for, but this seems much more difficult, and depending on the design you are working with might be unworkable.

Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1