# Can I go to a specific view if my apps icon has a badge on it (from push)?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, badge

I have push notifications setup.  I have the icons badge increment for every push, then disappear when the user taps the icon.  Is there a way I can know whether that badge is showing or not when the user taps the icon?  I want to go to a specific view if the badge is showing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996683/how-to-check-for-a-badge-number-on-app-launch-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to keep track of it yourself in the app. Your delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: will be called upon the notification and the user presses the action button and it receives the notification payload.

If you app is running in the foreground, the delegates application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: will be called. In this case you could have an integer value and increment it to keep track of the number of notifications you have. It also receives the notification payload

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1